# How to go back to client app from nodejs

Tags: node.js, cordova, express

I have a phonegap app which connects with a nodejs server.
In phonegap it looks like

app.html

```
<a href="http://server/click">click me</a>
```

now after some processing from http://server/click how can I go back to app's html page "clicked.html"?

Comment: What does `http://server/click` send ? A web page or JSON data ?

Comment: @AxelIsouard it actually doesn't send anything. my app page redirects to http://server/click then user can do something and after submit I want to redirect it back to another page on app